# Is the tag [sample-variance] needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

So we have [sample-variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample-variance), with 6 questions tagged. Three also have [variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variance) tagged, and all the questions were posted this year.

Simple question, is it desirable? There's also tag [estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) for example. If there's a consensus for it I'll try to improve the tag (and retag questions that deserve it).

But I can see arguments for it, as [sample-mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample-mean) exists.

Comment: I would say, [sample-variance] should be removed and replaced by [variance], and unless somebody protests here, you can go ahead and do the edits.

Comment: I am not sure but perhaps we could consider merging [sample-mean] into [mean]. I don't immediately see what it adds, and lots of the questions tagged with [mean] are presumably about sample means.

Comment: Finally, why did you mention [estimation]? I don't understand your 2nd paragraph. What does it have to do with sample-variance?

Comment: So, apparently we have 3 options regarding [sample-variance] and [sample-mean]: i) do nothing; ii) make them synonyms of [variance] and [mean], respectively; iii) manually edit posts to remove them (burninating)? Is that it?

Comment: @amoeba I mean double tagging [tag:variance] and [tag:estimation] as a substitution for [tag:sample-variance]

Comment: @AndreSilva sample-variance has 6 threads and can be taken care of in two minutes. In contrast, sample-mean has 100+ threads, that's why I suggested to make a synonym instead of manual retagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, I have removed [sample-variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample-variance) from all threads. The tag will be automatically deleted within 24h.

I note that the wiki excerpt for our [variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variance) tag explicitly says that it should be used for sample variances:

> The expected squared deviation of a random variable from its mean; or, the average squared deviation of data about their mean.

Comment: Actually, I can see that people who use Excel (and some calculators and some elementary texts) would go "But the *average squared deviation* means an $n$ denominator. Excel says that's the '*population standard deviation*' ... but I want *sample* standard deviation. Why isn't there a tag for it??" ... While we might all realize that the $n$ vs $(n-1)$ denominator thing *isn't* what makes a calculation a sample SD or a population SD, I think we should expect a large fraction of beginners to think otherwise.

Comment: Do you think this concern can be addressed with some appropriate edit of the wiki excerpt?

Comment: Yeah -- at least to the extent that users read them, I think it would help.

Comment: @amoeba and what about `[sample-mean]`..? The argument is actually the same, as you noted.

Comment: @Tim I posted it as a suggestion in our tag synonyms thread. Can you upvote it there? http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/4363/28666

Comment: @amoeba right, I see that I actually did it already...

Comment: ___ @Tim :-) ___